# I tried importing Pandas as pd in Jupyter notebook and got "AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'ndarray'"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py in 
20
21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat import (
23     np_version_under1p18 as _np_version_under1p18,
24     is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat_*init*_.py in 
12 import warnings
13
---> 14 from pandas._typing import F
15 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
16     is_numpy_dev,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_typing.py in 
82 # array-like
83
---> 84 ArrayLike = Union["ExtensionArray", np.ndarray]
85 AnyArrayLike = Union[ArrayLike, "Index", "Series"]
86

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'ndarray'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jupyter notebook, try uninstalling the numpy library using

```
! pip uninstall numpy
```

and then reinstalling the numpy

```
! pip install numpy
```

This is most likely an issue with your numpy library version and reinstalling will fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. I am so so grateful.